# Django Rest Framework sin estilos ni scripts

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Una vez tengo la **API** funcionando, al entrar en el entorno gráfico (**domain.com/API**) de pruebas me sale sin estilos, es decir que todos los [css](/questions/tagged/css) y los [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) no los puede encontrar.

En el `settings.py` he añadido los `STATIC_URL` y `STATIC_ROOT` después he hecho el `python manage.py collectstatic` y me ha puesto todos los de `admin` dentro del directorio, pero todo lo que son de `rest_framework` no.

He visto de otro post en Stack Overflow que decía de añadir `STATICFILES_DIRS` pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

Evidentemente he hecho un `service gunicorn restart` después de cada cambio.

Alguien podría iluminarme?

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/home/django/django_project/'),
)
```

Nadie sabe como cargar todos esos ficheros?

**ERROR**: Aquí dejo uno de los errores para que veáis la ruta a la que busca. La ruta a la que busca el navegador es:

`http://sub.domain.com/static/rest_framework/css/default.css`

El caso es que dentro de mi carpeta `static` están todos los ficheros.

**EDITO:** Al ejecutar el comando que dice @césar  me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
root@machine:/home/django/django_project# python manage.py findstatic rest_framework/css/default.css

/home/django/django_project/django_project/urls.py:33: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got my_app.views.home). Pass the callable instead.
  url(r'^$', 'my_app.views.home', name='home'),

/home/django/django_project/django_project/urls.py:37: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.
  url(r'^API', include(router.urls)),

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.

Found 'rest_framework/css/default.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/css/default.css
```

Nadie sabe como hacerlo? Alguna alma caritativa? He probado de todo y no hallo el modo.

**EDITO:** He borrado toda la carpeta `static` y he vuelto a hacer un `collectstatic` de nuevo y me sigue pasando lo mismo. (No encuentra las `img` de los boolean `/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg` y están en dicho directorio)

[image: Ejemplo del admin sin las imágenes]

[image: Ejemplo de la api todo perfecto]

Comment: ¿Qué resultado te arroja el siguiente comando: `python manage.py findstatic rest_framework/css/default.css`?

Comment: ¿Estás usando root para hacer todo?

Comment: Si, uso root, en un principio no, pero al final si, aunque el otro user que uso también tiene permisos sudo.

Comment: Si estás es producción, Django no sirve archivos estátícos, lo hace tu servidor web. Debes usar `collectstatic` para recolectarlos y poder servirlos.

Comment: Eso he hecho y veo que los copia todo dentro de mi carpeta /static, ahora bien, cuando abro el admin o el api rest sigue habiendo algunos estilos y imagenes que siguen sin aparecer.

Comment: Estas usando algún proxy inverso como **Nginx** o **Apache**?, le haz indicado la ruta de los estáticos?

Comment: Utilizo nginx, en principio no he tenido que tocar la configuración ya que he utilizado un droplet de DigitalOcean ante tantos problemas en el deployment. Como debo indicarlo en el nginx? Pensaba era suficiente con poner las rutas de los static y medias en el **settings.py** de Django.

Comment: Como tienes el archivo de configuracion del sitio en el nginx?, puedes seguir este tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Muchas gracias @castellbot había una incongruencia en la configuración del Nginx. Ahora si me aparece como toca el rest_framework, en cambio el backend admin me sigue fallando algún que otro .svg y .js en caso de entrar en el CRUD del sub apartado de mi app, en cambio en la raíz de admin sin ningún fallo en la consola. Sabes a que podría ser debido? O por donde vienen los palos?

Comment: @RuralGalaxy a mi me pasó algo parecido con la versión 1.9, a mi me funcionó eliminando la carpeta de estáticos y generarla de nuevo con collectstatic.

Comment: Lo he hecho, pero me sigue pasando lo mismo, en el admin los campos true/false no muestran la imagen, todo lo demás en principio funciona sin problemas. Actualizo el primer post con imágenes.

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que habrás resuelto el problema, partiendo del tiempo que tiene la pregunta. pero para dejar alguna respuesta para futuras consultas. Tienes un error en el settings del proyecto.

Cuando se declara BASE_DIR se obtiene la ruta raíz del proyecto, en tu caso el valor de la variable debe ser:

```
`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`
```

Lo que produce lo siguiente:

```
 BASE_DIR = '/home/django/django_project/'
```

Luego en el settings debemos crear rutas haciendo uso de BASE_DIR y no como lo has hecho con el string:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/static/'
```

Debe hacerse:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Luego en:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/home/django/django_project/'),
)
```

Le estas diciendo a Django que concatene BASE_DIR + BASE_DIR lo que produce:

'/home/django/django_project/home/django/django_project/'

Ruta que de seguro no existe en el sistema.

Lo que hace django con el collectstatic es buscar en estos directorios que agreguemos en STATICFILES_DIRS y copiarlos al STATIC_ROOT incluyendo por defecto todas las carpetas 'static' de las aplicaciones listadas en INSTALLED_APPS.
ejemplo: django.contrib.admin está instalado en site-packages:
PYTHONPATH + /site-packages/django/contrib/admin/ y dentro de esa carpeta existe 'static/admin/'

Collect static copiara todo lo que contenga el directorio 'static' al STATIC_ROOT.

Teniendo esto claro, entonces debemos verificar que todos los recursos estén presentes dentro del STATIC_ROOT.

y al servir el proyecto con apache, nginx o cualquier otro HTTP server debemos indicarle que todas las peticiones hechas a midominio.com/static las sirva directamente de la carpeta STATIC_ROOT y otorgar los permisos para que pueda acceder al directorio:

**Ejemplo apache:**

```
Alias /static /home/django/django_project/static/

<Directory /home/django/django_project/static/>
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Ejemplo Nginx:**

```
location /static {
    alias /home/django/django_project/static/; 
}
```

y para finalizar debes asegurarte que la carpeta STATIC_ROOT tenga permisos de lectura para todos los usuarios.

```
chmod -R +r  /home/django/django_project/static/
```

Con esto tendremos garantizados que todos los recursos estáticos estén disponibles.

Y tener presente, siempre en nuestras apps colocar los statics dentro de static/app_name/ a fin de evitar que nuestros ficheros sobre escriban los de otros:
ejemplo si colocas /home/django/django_project/app_name/static/admin/main.css y django.contrib.admin contiene main.css tu archivo main.css reemplazará el de admin y afectará el funcionamiento de admin.

Puesto que django colecta los archivos en el mismo orden que están listadas las apps en settings INSTALLED_APPS y admin estará antes que app_name.

Answer (score 0):

Debes correr el comando para que django extraiga los estáticos de todos los paquetes.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```